# Storing data from Axios Promise for multiple uses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I have created an endpoint in express that handles get requests. From a react component, I make a get request to said endpoint using axios. I want to store the data in an object in my Component class so that it can be accessed at multiple times (onComponentDidLoad, multiple onClick event handlers, etc). Is there a way to store the data outside of the axios promise, and/or preserve the promise so that I can do multiple .then calls without the promise being fulfilled?

I have tried using setState(), returning the promise, and returning the actual data from the get request.

Here is what I have right now:

```
constructor {
  super();
  this.myData = [];
  
  this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  this.storeData = this.storeData.bind(this);
  this.showData = this.showData.bind(this);
}

// Store data
storeData = (data) => {this.myData.push(data)};

// Get data from API
getData() {
    axios
        .get('/someEndpoint')
        .then(response => {
            let body = response['data'];

            if(body) {
                this.storeData(body);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

showData() {
    console.log(this.myData.length); // Always results in '0'
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getData();   // Get data
    this.showData();   // Show Data
}
    
render() {
  return(
      <Button onClick={this.showData}> Show Data </Button>
  );
}
```

**Edit**
I was incorrect in my question, storing the promise and then making multiple .then calls works. I had it formatted wrong when i tried it.

Comment: "*preserve the promise so that I can do multiple .then calls*" - yes, just do that

Comment: @Bergi that only works one time. After one .then call the promise fulfills and the data cannot be accessed anymore.

Comment: No. You can call `.then()` as many times as you want on the same promise. The callbacks are called as soon as the promise was fulfilled. A fulfilled promise does keep its value forever, it doesn't "loose it" somehow.

Comment: Oh shid u right not gonna lie @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't quite work because you're attempting to show the data without waiting it to be resolved:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getData();
    this.showData();
}
```

As you hinted toward in your original post, you'll need to extract the data from the Promise and there's no way to do that in a synchronous manner. The first thing you can do is simply store the original Promise and access it when required - Promises can be `then()`ed multiple times:

```
class C extends React.Component {
  state = {
    promise: Promise.reject("not yet ready")
  };

  showData = async () => {
    // You can now re-use this.state.promise.
    // The caveat here is that you might potentially wait forever for a promise to resolve.
    console.log(await this.state.promise);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const t = fetchData();
    this.setState({ promise: t });
    // Take care not to re-assign here this.state.promise here, as otherwise
    // subsequent calls to t.then() will have the return value of showData() (undefined)
    // instead of the data you want.
    t.then(() => this.showData());
  }
  
  render() {
    const handleClick = () => {
      this.showData();
    };

    return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to try to keep your component as synchronous as possible by limiting the asyncrony entirely to the fetchData() function, which may make your component a little easier to reason about:

```
class C extends React.Component {
  state = {
    status: "pending",
    data: undefined
  };

  async fetchData(abortSignal) {
    this.setState({ status: "pending" });
    try {
      const response = await fetch(..., { signal: abortSignal });
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data: data, status: "ok" });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ error: err, status: "error" });
    } finally {
      this.setState({ status: "pending" });
    }
  }

  showData() {
    // Note how we now do not need to pollute showData() with asyncrony
    switch (this.state.status) {
      case "pending":
        ...
      case "ok":
        console.log(this.state.data);
      case "error":
        ...
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Using an instance property is analogous to using a ref in React Hooks.
    // We don't want this to be state because we don't want the component to update when the abort controller changes.
    this.abortCtrl = new AbortController();
    this.fetchData(this.abortCtrl.signal);
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    this.abortCtrl.abort();
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.showData()}>Click Me</button>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just store the promise locally and access it as a promise it should work fine.

```
getData() {
  // if request has already been made then just return the previous request.
  this.data = this.data || axios.get(url)
  .then( response => response.data)
  .catch(console.log)
  return this.data
}

showData() {
  this.getData().then(d => console.log('my data is', data));
}
```

Comment: This works the first time showData() is called, but if I try to call showData more than once, the promise is 'fulfilled' and the result is null.

Comment: This will break if the promise errors at any point, but as long as axios is using a promise-compliant spec and you remove the catch() branch, it should work. that said, you should not be assigning to instance properties like this unless you never want the component to update when the instance property changes.